# python: efficient calling of multiple functions(returning boolean) with the same argument

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to find the best way to call multiple functions, each requiring the same argument, each returning a boolean value in the most efficient way.

```
def A(x):
    ....
    return x > 2

def B(x):
    ....
    return x < 10

def C(x):
    ....
    return x > 5

list_of_functions = [A, B, C]
result = [fun(x) for fun in list_of_functions]
```

Is there anything better I can do here? Also, can I apply some multiprocessing, would it make it a little faster?

Comment: Unless `A`, `B` and `C` are very expensive, or doing IO, I don't think you'd benefit from multi-processing here. Your way that you have is roughly what I'd go with if I felt the need to generalize the calling. Have you properly identified that as a bottleneck?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes they are pretty expensive functions unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, this highly depends on the actual work you are trying to do. And now:

> Is there anything better I can do here?

Doesn't look like it. Your solution seems straightforward and I personnaly can't think of a much more creative way of doing it. As to multiprocessing we will see next.

> can I apply some multiprocessing?

Well, yes. Almost to anything. One way is to use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)'s [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) in such a way that the worker function is a high-order function that operates on the functions list and runs each one on the static argument. So you could, for example, use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) method like:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

x = 5

def worker(func):
    return func(x)

def parallel():
    with Pool() as pool:
        return pool.map(worker, list_of_functions)
```

> would it make it a little faster?

So as I said in the start, this is highly dependent on your actual work. Very fast functions will not benefit from multiprocessing as the overhead will beat the benefit. A simple demonstration:

I took your example and ran as is (most simple functions) in both ways of operation:

```py
from timeit import timeit
from multiprocessing import Pool

x = 5

def A(x):
    return x > 2

def B(x):
    return x < 10

def C(x):
    return x > 5

def linear():
    return [fun(x) for fun in list_of_functions]

def worker(func):
    return func(x)

def parallel():
    with Pool() as pool:
        return pool.map(worker, list_of_functions)

list_of_functions = [A, B, C]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"linear running time: {timeit(linear, number=10)}")
    print(f"parallel running time: {timeit(parallel, number=10)}")
```

Timing this gives:

```
linear running time: 9.569999999992085e-05
parallel running time: 7.2561405
```

You can see that the parallel version is insanely slower. One way of reducing the gap is using threads instead of processes which have slightly lower overhead. This is done by changing the import statement to use the [`dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) version:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

this now gives:

```
linear running time: 4.3600000000143524e-05
parallel running time: 1.0739620000000003
```

**Now,** when adding some complexity, you can start seeing a difference. As I am not very creative, I simply added an incremental loop to the functions:

```py
def A(x):
    for i in range(1000000):
        x += 1
    return x > 2

def B(x):
    for i in range(1000000):
        x += 1
    return x < 10

def C(x):
    for i in range(1000000):
        x += 1
    return x > 5
```

Now the results were:

```
linear running time: 13.4436189
parallel running time: 10.7856389
```

We can still see the almost constant overhead of about 7 seconds as we would expect the parallel version to be a third of the time of the linear version (running the 3 functions at the same time).

---

<sup>running Python 3.7.3 using Windows10 on quad-core i7</sup>